# Derivative of SSE (sum of squared errors)

Tags: calculus

A linear regression formula follows the equation:

$\hat{y} = \theta_0 + \theta_1x_1 + \theta_2x_2 + ... + \theta_nx_n$

Where $\hat{y}$ is the prediction, and $y$ is the ground truth.

The sum of squared errors follows the equation (with $m$ being the number of samples):

$SSE = \sum_{i=1}^m (y_i - \hat{y}_i)^2$

When trying to calculate the derivative of the SSE respect to $\hat{y}_i$ I tried this:

$SSE' = 2 \sum_{i=1}^m (y_i - \hat{y}_i)$

I guess there is something wrong in my logic, because of the $\hat{y}_i$ term. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I'm kind of late to answer this post but i was searching for the answer myself and since no one has posted an answer I am going to try my best to explain it. Here is my take on the answer we suppose that any input
$\ I \in \mathbb{R}  $ based on that we can assume that the sum is "derivable" for almost any number on interval $\ x \in [1, m]$. Since you'd like to  "derive" the sum with respect to $\ \hat y $, we can assume that $\ (y_i - \hat y_i)^2 = f(y_i,\hat y_i) $. Now we can finally derive the function with respect to $\ \hat y $. $\ \frac{\partial f}{\partial \hat y_i} = \frac{\partial}{\partial \hat y_i} [(y_i - \hat y_i)^2] = \frac{\partial}{\partial \hat y_i} [y_i^2 -2y_i \hat y_i+\hat y_i^2] = - 2y_i + 2 \hat y_i$. Now we just sum all the partial derivatives.

$\ \Delta SSE =\sum_{i=1}^m \frac{\partial}{\partial \hat y_i} [(y_i - \hat y_i)^2]= \sum_{i=1}^m-2y_i+2 \hat y_i$.

Now let me explain why I have put "derive" in "" - You aren't really differentiating anything due to the fact that SSE is not a function. It would only be derivable if SSE would be a function of the same variables as is the sum on the right. Therefore you can hardly use "derived" SSE for anything, good luck though.